# "get_member_named" is not a known member of "None", error displaying on cogs.app_commands while outside cogs worked fine

Tags: discord.py, command, bots

atm I'm collecting all the **app_commands** onto **cogs** to reorder everything.

With the `pairings.py` I'm having struggles due to ***"get_member_named" is not a known member of "None"***, error displaying on **cogs.app_commands** while outside cogs worked just fine!

The pairings.py first version outside the cog was working perfectly, and was just the same. Unfortunately, if I try to run the code outside the cog, it doesn't work anymore.

These are the errors displayed:

[image: these are the errors displayed]

Here's the **cog.pairings**:

```
import discord
import settings
import typing
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from typing import Optional
from io import BytesIO
from datetime import datetime

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix ='!', intents = intents)

class Pairings(commands.Cog):
     
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command()
    @app_commands.describe(torneo = "Quale Torneo")
    @app_commands.describe(turni = "Quale Turno")
    @app_commands.describe(start = "A che ora parte il Turno da comunicare")
    @app_commands.describe(bye = "Se c'è il Bye")
    @app_commands.checks.has_any_role("ADMIN", "CONFERMATI")
    async def pairings(self, interaction : discord.Interaction, 
                       torneo : typing.Literal['Primo Torneo', 'Secondo Torneo'], 
                       turni : typing.Literal['Turno 1', 'Turno 2', 'Turno 3', 'Turno 4', 'Turno 5'],
                       start : str, 
                       bye : Optional[typing.Literal['Si', 'No']],
                       player_con_bye : Optional[str],
                       ):
        if bye == 'Si':

            guild = self.bot.get_guild(int(1156534000890953748))
            players = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=1156535561901838396)
            pairing_ch = self.bot.get_channel(int(1156534713805180989))
            bye_player = interaction.guild.get_member_named(player_con_bye)

            start_turno = datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
            start_turno_convertito = datetime.strftime(start_turno, '%H:%M')

            await interaction.response.send_message("Oki,Doki. Ora inviami l'immagine dei pairings!", ephemeral=True)
            message = await self.bot.wait_for('message')

            pairings_img = message.attachments[0]
            img_bytes = await pairings_img.read()

            await pairing_ch.send(f"{players.mention} \n\n**{torneo}** \n**{turni}** \n**Bye:** {bye_player.mention}  \n**{start_turno_convertito}**")
            await pairing_ch.send(file=discord.File(fp=BytesIO(img_bytes), filename=pairings_img.filename))

        else:

            guild = self.bot.get_guild(int(1156534000890953748))
            players = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=1156535561901838396)
            pairing_ch = self.bot.get_channel(int(1156534713805180989))

            start_turno = datetime.strptime(start, '%H:%M')
            start_turno_convertito = datetime.strftime(start_turno, '%H:%M')

            await interaction.response.send_message("Oki,Doki. Ora inviami l'immagine dei pairings!", ephemeral=True)
            message = await self.bot.wait_for('message')

            pairings_img = message.attachments[0]
            img_bytes = await pairings_img.read()

            await pairing_ch.send(f"{players.mention} \n\n**{torneo}** \n**{turni}** \n**{start_turno_convertito}**")
            await pairing_ch.send(file=discord.File(fp=BytesIO(img_bytes), filename=pairings_img.filename))

    @pairings.error
    async def on_error(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, error):
            if isinstance(error, app_commands.MissingAnyRole):
                await interaction.response.send_message("Non hai i permessi per usare questo comando!", ephemeral=True)



async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Pairings(bot))
```

and here's the **main.py**

```
import discord
import settings
import typing
from cogs.apertura_chiusura import Apertura_Chiusura
from cogs.iscrizioni import Iscrizione

from datetime import datetime
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from io import BytesIO
from typing import Optional

logger = settings.logging.getLogger("bot")


def run():
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    intents.members = True
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix ='!', intents = intents)


    #ON READY
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        logger.info(f"User: {bot.user.display_name} (ID: {bot.user.id})")
        bot_name = await bot.fetch_user(int(1155959555876991098)) 

        for cog_file in settings.COGS_DIR.glob("*.py"):
            if cog_file.name != "__init__.py":
                await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{cog_file.name[:-3]}")

        await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"SUUUUUUPER! SIAMO ON!")



    bot.run(settings.TOKEN, root_logger=True)
run()
```

I want to take the interaction input of `player_con_bye` which should always be the correct nickname of the member the app_commands.user is trying to achieve.

This choice is Optional due to previous choice selection `bye`

After this, the command should send a message with all the choices and mentioning the user who has the bye.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As guessed, after shutting down the bot, waiting for it to go offline and restarting it, the pairings.py works flawlessy.

For the Type Checking still has the errors mentioned above.

In case someone knows how to fix with the correct dictionary, please let me know!